# Class Dir. Creating an object. Ruby

Tags: ruby, object, directory

I am new to Ruby and to programming in general. Currently, I am working with Dir class in Ruby. I'm trying to create a Dir object and then use the Dir methods on this object. However, I do something wrong. This is a little code that I use.

```
$LOAD_PATH
puts Dir.getwd
puts Dir.glob("*.rb")
```

this works just fine. I can see my current directory and list all the files with .rb extention.

```
kd = Dir.new("N:/Data-Analytics/Products")
puts kd.getwd
```

Here, I created an object kd indicating other directory. However, I have a message that getwd is an undefined method. Isn't kd an object of Dir?

Thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 0):

Of course `kd` is an object of `Dir`...But, the method `getwd` is a Public class method not a Public instance method. So, `getwd` doesn't work with objects. You should use it like `Dir.getwd` only...
If you want to change directory and get the current working directory, which I assume is your requirement, you can do like...

```
Dir.chdir("N:/Data-Analytics/Products") #changes the current working directory
```

and then run,

`Dir.getwd` or `Dir.pwd` `# gets current working directory`

Comment: I do not understand why the method entries works with my object kd, but getwd does not. These two methods are listed among the methods for Dir class.

Comment: @Ona `Dir` includes `Enumerable`, so `kd.entries` is actually [`Enumerable#entries`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries). It's equivalent to calling `kd.each.to_a`

Comment: Yes as @Stefan said, .entries works as Dir includes Enumerable...If you really want to know what are all the instance methods that are available for Dir class you can always do `Dir.instance_methods` in irb...

Comment: `Dir.instance_methods` merely returns a list of symbols. It doesn't explain where the methods come from.

Comment: Yeah true, I told this so that OP can make use of the list and code accordingly next time.